# How to resolve this circular inheritance issue with template?

Tags: c++, class, oop, templates

I have the following class:

```
template<class T>
class Base: public Root //this one abstract
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> components;
}

template<class T>
class Derived : Base<T> //this one not abstract
{
 //stuff
}
```

I'm building:

```
Derived<Base<Root>> myDerived;
std::shared_ptr<Base<Root>> ptr_base;
ptr_base.reset(&myDerived); // -> ERROR
```

Compiler give me :

```
error C2664: 'std::_Ptr_base<_Ty>::_Reset0' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'model::Derived <T> *' to 'model::Base<T> *'
```

So the compiler doesnt seems to get that a `Derived<Base<Root>>` is also a `Base<Root>` because in what im trying to do:

1.`Base<Root> is Root` from the definition of Base

2.`Derived<T>` is `Base<T>` from the definition of `Derived<T>`

so `Derived<Base<Root>>` is `Base<Root>`

Any hints ?

Thks.

Comment: It's not an answer but destructor of `Base` should be virtual. In other case `shared_ptr` won't call destructor of `Derived`.

Comment: `Derived<Base<Root>>` would be `Base<Root>` if inheritance was applied like this: `template<class T> class Derived : public T `. The way it's now you end up with `Derived : Base<Base<Root>>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Derive<T>` is `Based<T>`, hence `Derived<Base<Root>>` is `Base<Base<Root>>`.

Now the question is: Is `Base<Base<Root>>` a `Base<Root>`?

In other words: Does `Base<Base<Root>>` derive from `Base<Root>`?

Or equivalently:  Does `Base<A>` derive from `Base<B>`, with A=`Base<Root>` and B=Root?

No. A derives from B, but `Base<A>` doesn't derive from `Base<B>`.

Just the same way a `vector<X>` doesn't derive from `vector<Y>`, even if X inherits Y.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you expect the template parameter of `Derived`, i.e. `Base<Root>`, to be 'upcasted' to `Root`. The cast would work for an object, but cannot happen for a template parameter: specializing a template defines a new type that is different from other specializaions.

`Derived<Base<Root>>` can be casted to `Base<Base<Root>>`, but not to `Derived<some-ancestor-of-Base<Root>>`.

In general, if `Derived` inherits from `Base`, then `AnyClass<Derived>` cannot be casted to `AnyClass<Base>`.